# Is there a straightforward way to replace a model based on a unique constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, replace, save, ruby-on-rails-5, unique

With Rails 5, what's the most elegant way to write a replace save method based on a uniqueness constraint in my model?  This is my model with the two columns that define a unique constraint

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :person, scope: [:user]
end
```

In my controller, I'd like to invoke logic to save a vote, by doing

```
  # Rate someone!
  def create
    user = current_user
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
    @vote.user = user
    @vote.save!
  end
```

However the above doesn't work if the user has already voted on that person.  In such a case, i'd like to delete their previous vote and create a new vote (or edit the existing one).  Is there an easy way to do a transactional insert/update based on whether the unique constraint exists?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

```
# Rate someone!
def create
  @vote = Vote.find_or_create_by(person_id: vote_params[:person_id])
  @vote.user = current_user
  @vote.save!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `first_or_create`

```
def create
  @vote = Vote.where(person_id: vote_params[:person_id], user: current_user).first_or_create.update(vote_params)
end
```

It will look for the `Vote` with the current `User` and `Person`, if it exists it will `Update` it, if it doesn't it will create it.

(It will make only one `INSERT`)